# How to call a stored pgsql function from Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, function, sql-view

I created a stored function in PostgreSQL : `myfunction(a text, b integer)`.
I want to create an SQL View in Geoserver using this query : `Select * from myfunction('%nom%', %likes%)`.

My problem is that Geoserver don't recognize my function. And thus when I click on "refresh" nothing is displayed.

Comment: Did you get any error when call PostgreSQL function in geoserver?